# Need help creating a random number generating button in google sheets

Tags: javascript, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, random

I want to generate a random number between 1 and the value in cell "a2" on the same sheet using a button. Is this possible?

```
function onOpen() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var entries = [ {name:"Roll Dice",functionName:"rollDice"} ]; 
  sheet.addMenu("Script", entries); }; 

function rollDice() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing"); 
 var cell = sheet.getRange("a4"); 
 var range = sheet.getRange("a2"); 
 cell.setValue(Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1) ); };
```

Comment: Yes, I recommend you to do it with Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions

Comment: Your question is very vague and people might want to close/down vote it. Please elaborate more on what you tried. In the meantime check my answer which addresses your problem.

Comment: I know how to create the button. And I have script that will generate a number between 1 and 6, but I don't know how to have it generate a number between 1 and cell "a2"

Comment: function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [ {name:"Roll Dice",functionName:"rollDice"} ];
  sheet.addMenu("Script", entries);
};

function rollDice() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("a4");
  var range = sheet.getRange("a2");
  cell.setValue(Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1) );

};

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

- The following script will get the value of cell `A2` and generate an `integer` number between `1` and the value of cell `A2` and paste it into cell `B2`. Modify the last part in the code if you want. If you want a float number between the same ranges then comment the first `rn` line and comment out the second one.
- We attach this script to a picture button so you can execute it from the `UI`. Be gentle with how many times you press the button within a particular time frame because it needs some time to process your requests.
- The function we are using is [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

---

### Solution:

You can create an image button attached to the following script:

```
function button() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rf = sh.getRange('A2').getValue();
  const rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * rf) + 1;
//const rn = Math.random() * rf + 1; //if you want a float number
  sh.getRange('B2').setValue(rn);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

---

### Instructions:

Copy an image of your choice in the sheet and then follow the instructions in the following gif:

[image: example]